# What is the best practice to store a MM-DD data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to store some dates into MySQL but those dates are without years field.
What's the best way to do it?

It's best if I can utilize those two MySQL functions in my queries: `DATE_SUB()`, `DATE_ADD()`; because I want to query date spans that covers the current MM-DD.

ADD:

1. I have 100% control over the input and output code;
2. I have two MM-DD dates in a row to represent a date span
3. I'm not intending to save space by doing this, but I'm doing this just because in my requirements I need to store important MM-DD dates and return the date span that covers current MM-DD no matter what year it is now, it's like a "holiday reminder" or something like that

Comment: You should improve the number of accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 100% control over all the code that directly reads or writes this data, you could just use a normal `DATE` field, and always set the year to the same constant value.

Then, you can use `DATE_ADD()` etc. in your queries normally, you just have to omit the year whenever you return some of those dates.

Answer (score 2):

What about storing the data using the `date` type and then just use the part of the date you need? In this way, if you'll change the behavior of you app, you can because you've thought your app thinking to the future (and to possible future change). Moreover you'll be able to use all the date built-in functions.

In addition, storing in some strange way just months and days, you will not even save space.

Comment: Yup... what would happen if user needed to know what happened on June 14 last yr vs this year vs any other... Best to have ENOUGH data than to try and back-fill it.